# CDI - simulate request scope?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-7

I have a lot of RequestScoped CDI services and I would like to use them in an ApplicationScoped batch job.

I'd like to have a service that processes user notifications in the background: extracts them from the database, sends them, marks as sent. It would process each item in a separate transaction.
I thought I should create a request scope for each batch item in some way.

How is this possible?

Comment: CDI is not a service layer framework. CDI is a dependency injection framework. So CDI can't do anything for you with regard to transactions. Are you using EJB or not? I.e. `@Stateless`, `@TransactionAttribute` and friends. They are capable of managing transactions for you.

Comment: For some reason, `@javax.transaction.Transactional` works with my CDI beans. But I cannot use them in the batch job, because they're `@RequestScoped`. This's why I thought I should create a request scope for each batch job item...

Comment: Your use case seems much more appropriately for a singleton ejb bean, rather than CDI beans. Additionally, you can define this beans as stateless session beans, and let the CDI requestscoped beans delegate their operations to the stateless session beans, and hence you dont have to duplicate code

Comment: Thanks @maress, this's what I did, and it works. `@RequestScope` is active in a `@Stateless` bean invocation, so I've simply wrapped the notification sender logic into an EJB. The batch task just invokes it.Shouldn't you post it as a solution? Then I can accept it.